# Homomorphism $\lambda:\mathbb C^*\rightarrow\mathbb C^*$ is a monic polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves

I'm self-studying Silverman and Tate's *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*, and I came across this exercise:

> **Exercise 6.3:** 
> (a) Suppose that $\lambda(z)=a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}z+a_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $\lambda:\mathbb C^*\rightarrow \mathbb C^*$ is a homomorphism. Prove that $\lambda(z)=z^n$.
> (b) Suppose that $\lambda(z)$ is a meromorphic function such that $\lambda:\mathbb C^*\rightarrow \mathbb C^*$ is a homomorphism. Prove that $\lambda(z)=z^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z$.

This book doesn't depend on much  complex analysis, so I was initially thrown off and tried to solve this with elliptic curves/Galois groups. I considered using Rouche's theorem or Liouville's theorem, but Rouche's theorem only gives the number of zeros (which is already clear through the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), and Liouville's theorem implies $z^n$ would be constant if I could find a bound for the polynomial $\lambda(z)$. I also tried using Little/Big Picard (which seems the most promising), but I'm stumped on "narrowing down" $\lambda(z)$ to a monic, single-term polynomial.

I have two main questions:

1. I'm not sure how to prove the statements, as the standard theorems I've looked at do not fully satisfy the claim. I'm thinking of different ways to bound/modify $\lambda(z)$ such that it behaves closer to $z^n$ as $z\rightarrow \infty$, but that doesn't solve the issue of local behavior (especially around $z=0$)
2. The focus of the chapter was on complex multiplication, abelian extensions over the rationals, and how elliptic curves were used to prove Fermat's last theorem. *How does this question relate to the content of the chapter?* Theorem 6.16 states that a rational map that preserves the identity element/projective point at infinity (in the group law) between two elliptic curves is a homomorphism – is this exercise meant to bridge a gap between homomorphisms between elliptic curves and general polynomials, or address some other aspect of rational functions?

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda$ had any non-zero root, then $\lambda$ would not even be a *map* from $\Bbb C^\times$ to $\Bbb C^\times$.

Same with poles.